# Difference Amplifier with 3 Op. Amp. How to analyze it?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, differential

I have to demonstrate, in the following circuit, that \$ V_o= \left( 1+\frac{2R_2}{R1}\right)(V_2-V_1) \$ if the Pot is in the halfway.

[image: 3 Op. Amp. Difference Amplifier]

I know that the circuit inside the pink block its a Buffer for the differential inputs and that \$R_1\$ can adjust the Gain, but I don't know how Op. Amp. 3 is participating.

In order to facilitate the analysis, I split the Pot as shown in the image below pretending to do a current analysis, but I don't know how to interpretate the output voltage of the 3rd amplifier.

[image: Circuit 1 redrawn]

How should I interpret this circuit?

Comment: I find it strange that OA3 has no negative feedback… It may behave as a comparator, but that’s somewhat surprising…

Comment: You have it simulated.  What happens when you tweak R3 and R4 (250Ω and 750Ω)?  It should give you a clue.

Comment: OA1 and OA2 aren't powered in your simulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Who doesn't like a good old \$Y - \Delta \$ transform: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-Δ_transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform) ? [EDIT after solving the question: might not be necessary].

The computed equivalent values for the \$ \Delta \$ are:

\$R_{eq1} = \frac{R_1R_1+2R_3R_1}{4R_3}\$

\$R_{eq3} = \frac{R_1+2R_3}{2}\$

The op-amps 1 & 2 have negative feedback so we can assume they are not in saturation and for them \$v_+ = v_- \$.

The current \$i_2\$ across \$R_{2top}\$ is equal to:

\$i_2 = \frac{v_o-v_2}{R_2} = \frac{v_2-v_1}{R_{eq1}}+\frac{v_2-v_{oa}}{R_{eq3}}\$ [1]

The current \$i_1\$ across \$R_{2bot}\$ is equal to:

\$i_1 = \frac{v_1-v_y}{R_2} = \frac{v_2-v_1}{R_{eq1}}+\frac{v_{oa}-v_{1}}{R_{eq3}}\$ [2]

From [1] we derive:

\$ \frac{v_{oa}}{R_{eq3}} = \frac{v_2-v_o}{R_2} + \frac{v_2-v_1}{R_{eq1}}+\frac{v_2}{R_{eq3}}\$ [3]

From [2] we derive:

\$ \frac{v_{oa}}{R_{eq3}} = \frac{v_1-v_y}{R_2} + \frac{v_1-v_2}{R_{eq1}}+\frac{v_{1}}{R_{eq3}}\$ [4]

Isolating \$ v_{oa} \$

\$ v_{oa} =\frac{R_{eq3}(v_1-v_y)}{R_2}+\frac{R_{eq3}(v_1-v_2)}{R_{eq1}}+v_{1}\$

\$ v_y \$ & \$ v_{oa} \$ have opposite signs in this equation! So it turns out there is **negative feedback** from \$ v_y \$ on \$ v_{oa} \$. This explains the stability of the circuit.

So we can assume \$ v_y = 0 \$ (this is the big trick of this exercise - you can indeed verify that v_y is 0 in simulations). So now it is easier from [3] = [4] and setting  \$ v_y = 0 \$ we get:

\$ \frac{v_2-v_o}{R_2} + \frac{v_2-v_1}{R_{eq1}}+\frac{v_2}{R_{eq3}} = \frac{v_1}{R_2} + \frac{v_1-v_2}{R_{eq1}}+\frac{v_{1}}{R_{eq3}}\$

\$ \frac{v_o}{R_2} = \frac{v_2-v_1}{R_2} + \frac{v_2-v_1}{R_{eq1}} + \frac{v_2-v_1}{R_{eq3}}\$

\$ v_o = (v_2-v_1) \left(1 + \frac{R_2}{R_{eq1}} + \frac{R_2}{R_{eq3}}\right)\$

\$ v_o = (v_2-v_1) \left(1 + \frac{4R_3R_2}{R_1R_1+2R_3R_1} + \frac{2R_1R_2}{R_1R_1+2R_3R_1}\right)\$

\$ v_o = (v_2-v_1) \left(1 + \frac{2R2(2R_3+R_1)}{R_1(R_1+2R_3)}\right)\$

\$ v_o = (v_2-v_1) \left(1 + \frac{2R2}{R_1}\right)\$
Hence the answer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK32x3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>